# My Test Class is not covered

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, vlocity

I cannot cover my test class ,its always on 18% or 12% ,i have a vlocity Class apex ,my class needs 3 parameters (inputMap) that we should pass in our test class , when i try to pass this parameters in my test class ,my covertage is not increased ,for example the first parameter which is (Selectedoconfig)expects in my class an object  ,i create a json  and i convertit to an object and i passed this object to my input but it doesn't work ,
i need your help please ,i put below also all the lines covered and lines not covered + (Class + Test Class)

```
global with sharing class SetAttributes implements vlocity_cmt.VlocityOpenInterface2 {
    
    
    global Boolean invokeMethod(String methodName, Map<String,Object> inputMap, Map<String,Object> outputMap, Map<String,Object> options) {
        Boolean success = true;
        
        try {
            if (String.isNotBlank(methodName)) {
                if (methodName.equalsIgnoreCase('setAttributesConfiguration')) setAttributesConfiguration(inputMap, outputMap, options);
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
        }
        
        return success;        
    }
    
    public static void setAttributesConfiguration(Map <String, Object> inputMap, Map <String, Object> outMap, Map <String, Object > options) {
              Object selecte =  inputMap.get('selectedConfig') ;
        list<Object> selectedConfig = (list<Object>) selecte ;

      //  list<Object> selectedConfig = (list<Object>) inputMap.get('selectedConfig') ;
        string pricelistentryid = string.valueof(inputMap.get('pricelistentryid')) ;
        string subquote = string.valueof(inputMap.get('subquote')); 
        String sourceproductname = [select Id ,name from PricebookEntry where Id=:pricelistentryid].name;
        QuoteLineItem qLIServiceoffer = [select Id,Product2.name,vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c,PriceBookEntry.Product2.vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c,vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = :subquote and Product2.name = :sourceproductname];
       list<QuoteLineItem> qLIAccesdediee = [select Id,Product2.name,vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c,PriceBookEntry.Product2.vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c,vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = :subquote and Product2.name = 'Accès sur Fibre Dédiée'];
 //QuoteLineItem qLIServiceoffer = [select Id,Product2.name,vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c,PriceBookEntry.Product2.vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c,vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = '0Q05E0000011XDfSAM' and Product2.name = :sourceproductname];
       //list<QuoteLineItem> qLIAccesdediee = [select Id,Product2.name,vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c,PriceBookEntry.Product2.vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c,vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = '0Q05E0000011XDfSAM' and Product2.name = 'Accès sur Fibre Dédiée'];

        system.debug('lineitem' +qLIServiceoffer);
        system.debug('nerminedebug' +selectedConfig);
        String AttributeCodeZone = Null ;
        String AttributeValueZone = Null;
        String AttributeCodeDebit = Null;
        String AttributeValueDebit = Null ;
        String AttributeCodeOperateur = Null;
        String AttributeValueOperateur= Null ;
        for (Object config :selectedConfig) {
            Map<String, Object> setconfiguration = (Map<String, Object>) config;
            if (setconfiguration.get('code')=='BTE_ATTR_TARIFICATION') {
                AttributeCodeZone = String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('code'));
                AttributeValueZone =String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('value'));                
            }
            else if (setconfiguration.get('code')=='BTE_ATTR_OPERATEUR_COLLECTE') {
                AttributeCodeOperateur = String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('code'));
                AttributeValueOperateur =String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('value'));                
            }
            else if (setconfiguration.get('code')=='BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_DESCENDANT') {
                AttributeCodeDebit = String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('code'));
                AttributeValueDebit =String.valueof(setconfiguration.get('value'));                
            }
            
            
            
        }
        system.debug('zonename' +AttributeCodeZone);
        system.debug('zonevalue' +AttributeValueZone);
        system.debug('debitename' +AttributeCodeDebit);
        system.debug('debitvalue' +AttributeValueDebit);
        system.debug('operateurname' +AttributeCodeOperateur);
        system.debug('operateurvalue' +AttributeValueOperateur);
        system.debug('pricelistentry' +pricelistentryid);
        system.debug('sourceproductname' +sourceproductname);
        
        if (sourceproductname =='Service Internet sur Fibre Dédiée') {
            List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest> actionRequestsList = new List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest>();
            actionRequestsList.add(new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest(AttributeCodeZone, vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.ActionType.ASSIGN, AttributeValueZone)); 
            actionRequestsList.add(new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest(AttributeCodeDebit, vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.ActionType.ASSIGN, AttributeValueDebit)); 

            /* prepare data and invoke Vlocity API */
            Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> outputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> optionsMap = new Map <String, Object>();
            inputs.put('originalAttributesMetadata', qLIServiceoffer.getSObject('PriceBookEntry').getSObject('Product2').get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c'));
            inputs.put('runTimeAttributesValuesJSON', qLIServiceoffer.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c'));
            inputs.put('runtimeAttributesMetadataJSON', qLIServiceoffer.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c'));
            inputs.put('JSONAttributeActionRequestList', actionRequestsList);
            vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport jsonSupport = new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport();
            jsonSupport.invokeMethod('applyAttributeActions', inputs, outputMap, optionsMap);
            qLIServiceoffer.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c', outputMap.get('attributesValues'));
            qLIServiceoffer.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c', outputMap.get('attributesMetadataChanges'));
            
            update qLIServiceoffer;
        }
             
        if(!qLIAccesdediee.isEmpty())   {
          QuoteLineItem qi=  qLIAccesdediee[0];
              List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest> actionRequestsList = new List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest>();
            actionRequestsList.add(new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest(AttributeCodeOperateur, vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.ActionType.ASSIGN, AttributeValueOperateur)); 

            // prepare data and invoke Vlocity API */
           Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
           Map<String, Object> outputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
           Map<String, Object> optionsMap = new Map <String, Object>();
          inputs.put('originalAttributesMetadata', qi.getSObject('PriceBookEntry').getSObject('Product2').get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c'));
          inputs.put('runTimeAttributesValuesJSON', qi.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c'));
          inputs.put('runtimeAttributesMetadataJSON', qi.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c'));
          inputs.put('JSONAttributeActionRequestList', actionRequestsList);
          vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport jsonSupport = new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport();
          jsonSupport.invokeMethod('applyAttributeActions', inputs, outputMap, optionsMap);
           qi.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c', outputMap.get('attributesValues'));
            qi.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c', outputMap.get('attributesMetadataChanges'));
            
            update qLIAccesdediee;
        } 
         if (sourceproductname =='Service Internet sur Fibre Entreprise') {
            List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest> actionRequestsList = new List<vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest>();
            actionRequestsList.add(new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.JSONAttributeActionRequest(AttributeCodeZone, vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport.ActionType.ASSIGN, AttributeValueZone)); 

            /* prepare data and invoke Vlocity API */
            Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> outputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> optionsMap = new Map <String, Object>();
            inputs.put('originalAttributesMetadata', qLIServiceoffer.getSObject('PriceBookEntry').getSObject('Product2').get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c'));
            inputs.put('runTimeAttributesValuesJSON', qLIServiceoffer.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c'));
            inputs.put('runtimeAttributesMetadataJSON', qLIServiceoffer.get('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c'));
            inputs.put('JSONAttributeActionRequestList', actionRequestsList);
            vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport jsonSupport = new vlocity_cmt.JSONAttributeSupport();
            jsonSupport.invokeMethod('applyAttributeActions', inputs, outputMap, optionsMap);
            qLIServiceoffer.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c', outputMap.get('attributesValues'));
            qLIServiceoffer.put('vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c', outputMap.get('attributesMetadataChanges'));
            
            update qLIServiceoffer;
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

My test class

```
@isTest
public class BYTEL_SetAttributesTest {
    static void testData() {
        
    }
    
    static testMethod void testinvokeMethod() {
   
        string methodName = 'setAttributesConfiguration';
        SetAttributes obj = new SetAttributes();
        Map<String, Object> inputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> outputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> options = new Map<String, Object>();
         TEST.startTest();
    Product2 pr1 = new Product2(Name = 'Service Internet sur Fibre Dédiée');
        insert pr1;
   PriceBookEntry pre = new PriceBookEntry(PriceBook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), Product2Id = pr1.Id , UnitPrice=123);
        insert pre;
    //   String str ='{"selectedConfig":[{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_TARIFICATION","value":"Z4"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_OPERATEUR_COLLECTE","value":"BOUYGUES TELECOM"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_DESCENDANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_MONTANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_GARANTI_DESCENDANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_GARANTI_MONTANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT"}]}';
         String str ='[{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_TARIFICATION","value":"Z4"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_OPERATEUR_COLLECTE","value":"BOUYGUES TELECOM"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_DESCENDANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_MONTANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_GARANTI_DESCENDANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT","code":"BTE_ATTR_DEBIT_GARANTI_MONTANT","value":"20 Mbps"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT"},{"SourcePriceListEntry":"01u5E00000DHq9AQAT"}]';
 PriceBookEntry price = [Select id, name from PriceBookEntry where name = 'Service Internet sur Fibre Dédiée'];
          inputMap.put('pricelistentryid',pre.Id);
        inputMap.put('selectedConfig',JSON.deserializeUntyped(str));
      obj.invokeMethod(methodName, inputMap, outputMap, options);
              TEST.stopTest();
        
    }
    
    
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: @NagendraSingh It's not a trigger, and specifically it's a problem with logic bugs. I don't think our canonical questions cover this, at least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your code fails on:

```
    QuoteLineItem qLIServiceoffer = [select Id,Product2.name,vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadataChanges__c,PriceBookEntry.Product2.vlocity_cmt__AttributeMetadata__c,vlocity_cmt__AttributeSelectedValues__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId = :subquote and Product2.name = :sourceproductname];
```

Because you never provided a value for `subquote` in your JSON.

In addition, you have hard-coded ID values in your unit test, and you cannot query production records in a unit test (with some exceptions) because of [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). You need to fix your payload so that all records are created in your unit test, and are properly referenced.

Comment: the values in my json are not referenced in database ,at least  this code for (Object config :selectedConfig) {    }  should be covered  because i passed to my input the selectedconfig object ,my question ,if  a line fails before this code ,so i cannot cover it until i resolve the issue with line that you have send in your comment?

Comment: @user3499987 you need to set up your data correctly before you can even get to that line. Your test fails because you have an assignment from a query to a scalar value, which throws an exception because no rows were found.